# How to calculate birthdate from age and current date in R

Tags: r, date-arithmetic

I only have the ages of the participants and the current date (the age is presented in years like 56.07231). Now I need to know their birth date.

How can I do that in R? All I can found online is how to calculate age from two dates. Thanks!

Comment: You only have the age in years? Or years + days? If it's the former, you're not going to be able to do it accurately.

Comment: @thelatemail I have age in days---it was presented as like 57.0631.

Comment: So to clarify, 57.0631 days? Or 57 years and .0631 years representing days?

Comment: @thelatemail Sorry for the confusing reply. I've edited the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution would be to use duration objects from the lubridate package.
Your question is not specific, but the package can handle different ways to calculate time using also the %m-% operator to subtract dates.

Examples below

```
library(lubridate)

##If the person is 57.0631 days old, you can get their birth date by doing

ymd("2021-07-06") %m-% seconds(ddays(57.0631)@.Data) ##2021-05-10

##If the person is 57.0631 years old, you can do:

ymd("2021-07-06") %m-% seconds(dyears(57.0631)@.Data) ##1964-06-26
```

Comment: It worked for me. Thanks! I've edited the question to make it clearer.

Comment: If it solved your problem, would you mind upvoting and accepting the answer?